# Informations are not sent by form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, session

I wrote a code and i used Boostrap to make 2 dropdown : Sign In and Sign Up. After i complete input fields , informations aren't send ... and submit button redirect me to index.php?username="What is in username field"&password="Password typed" .

I wanna send data to informations index.php?tab=SignIn... What could be wrong ?

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav pull-right">
        <li class="animated dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i><br /> Register <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<?php
@$_SESSION['username2'] = $_POST['username'];
@$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
@$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
?>
          <form class="form" id="formLogin" action="index.php?tab=SignUp"> 

           <li><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="<?= $_SESSION['username2'] ?>" required/>
                            </div></li>
                            <li><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail Address" value="<?= $_SESSION['email'] ?>" required/>
                            </div></li>
                            <li><div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" value="<?= $_SESSION['password'] ?>" required/>
                            </div></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
            <input type="submit" name="register" class="btn btn-success" value="Register" tabindex="7">
          </form>
          </ul>
          </li>  
       </ul>
```

Comment: Your `action` is set to `Signup` not `Signin`

Comment: Use 'method="post"` in your form

Comment: @HoboSapiens, that's true. I told i have 2 dropdown, so i copied source from one. Now works fine ! I forget method="POST"... Thank you  !

Answer (score 1):

replace this

```
<form class="form" id="formLogin" action="index.php?tab=SignUp">
```

with this

```
<form class="form" id="formLogin" action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="tab" value="SingUp" />
```

and in your index.php get tab parameter by $_POST['tab']

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<form class="form" id="formLogin" action="index.php?tab=SignUp">
```

to

```
<form class="form" id="formLogin" action="index.php?tab=SignUp" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Just call index.php each time. No suffixes to the url ever.  If you want a special value, then create a hidden element in the form, with the value set so the second time the user hits index.html, the value will populate...

```
<?php
@$_SESSION['username2'] = $_POST['username'];
@$_SESSION['tab'] = $_POST['tab'];   // set in the original form in a hidden field.
@$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
@$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];
?>
```

Somewhere along the line do a test `if ($_POST['tab'] == "SignUp")` then do whatever.  If $_POST['tab'] isnt = SignUp, then you know its the first time to that page....

Keep it very simple.  Less is more!  (oops.. I'm a duplicate of the posting by Gabriele Pieretti)  I'm upvoting GP!  thx.